# How to query without getting duplicate data?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which has a join on another table:

```
select * from tbl_scales s
join tbl_recipes r on r.category_id = s.product_id
```

and it displays redundant data like this,

```
scale_id    r_id     date       recipe_name

1       1   2012-05-20  Cheese Bread
6       1   2012-05-21  Cheese Bread
1       1   2012-05-20  Spanish Bread
6       1   2012-05-21  Spanish Bread
3       4   2012-05-20  Pancake
8       4   2012-05-21  Pancake
1       1   2012-05-20  Pandesal
6       1   2012-05-21  Pandesal
```

i don't know how to do this..can someone help me?

Comment: What is duplicate, every row is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT will eliminate rows that have equal data in columns. But since your date is different you probably want to use GROUP BY recipe_name (add on the end of your query).

Answer (score 1):

The [distinct](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL) keyword is your friend.

```
select distinct r_id, scale_id, recipe_name from tbl_scales s
join tbl_recipes r on r.category_id = s.product_id
```